# In array listitem how to store values with comma separation and end with dot using perl

Tags: regex, perl

```
 use strict;
 use warnings;

 my $tmp = join "\n", <DATA>;
 my @biblables = ();
```

List items will be fetched and storing into @biblables in a while loop

```
 while($tmp=~m/\\bibitem\[([^\[\]]*)\]{([^\{\}]*)}/g)
 {
      push(@biblables, "\\cite{$2}, ");
 }

 print @biblables;
```

While printing this we are getting the output like as:

```
 \cite{BuI2001},\cite{BuI2002},\cite{BuI2003},\cite{BuI2004},\cite{BuI2005},\cite{BuI2006},
```

However we need the output like this

```
 \cite{BuI2001},\cite{BuI2002},\cite{BuI2003},\cite{BuI2004},\cite{BuI2005},\cite{BuI2006}.
```

Hence we can use post regex to insert dot at the end of the listitem in array

```
 while($tmp=~m/\\bibitem\[([^\[\]]*)\]{([^\{\}]*)}/g)
 {
      my $post = $';
      if($post!~m/\\bibitem\[([^\[\]]*)\]{([^\{\}]*)}/)
      {  push(@biblables, "\\cite{$2}.");  }
      else {  push(@biblables, "\\cite{$2}, ");  }
 }

 print @biblables;
```

Could you please advise me if there is short way to get this output

```
#
__DATA__    
\bibitem[{BuI (2001)}]{BuI2001}    
\bibitem[{BuII (2002)}]{BuI2002}    
\bibitem[{BuIII (2003)}]{BuI2003}    
\bibitem[{BuIV (2004)}]{BuI2004}    
\bibitem[{BuV (2005)}]{BuI2005}    
\bibitem[{BuVI (2006)}]{BuI2006}
```

Comment: I don't know much of perl, but why don't you join the array matches and add a dot at the end?

Comment: @user6188402: Based and on the requirement we need to insert end punctuation at the end of the statement or sentence. The number of the items should be splitted by comma or semicolon whatever it may be. However we need end period at the end of the line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read from a filehandle you can use `eof` to determine that you are on the last line, at which point you replace the comma by the dot in the last element.  This allows you to build the array completely in the loop, as required.

```
use warnings;
use strict;

open my $fh, '<', 'bibitems.txt';

my @biblabels;

while (<$fh>) {
    push @biblabels, "\\cite{$2}," if /\\bibitem\[([^\[\]]*)\]{([^\{\}]*)}/;
    $biblabels[-1] =~ tr/,/./      if eof;
}

print "$_ " for @biblabels;
print "\n";
```

This prints your desired output.

The `oef` returns true if the next read will return *end-of-file*. This means that you've just read the last line, which got put on the array if it matched. This function is rarely needed but here it seems to find a fitting purpose. Note that `eof` and `eof()` behave a little differently. Please see the [eof](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eof.html) page.

---

If the other capture in the regex is meant to be used change the above to `if (...) { ... }`. Note that what is in `{}` is in Latex called *citation keys*, while the (optional) *labels* are things inside `[]`. I'd go with the array name of `@citkeys` for clarity.

Answer (score 7):

You can add the comma and period after the fact:

```
while($tmp=~m/\\bibitem\[([^\[\]]*)\]{([^\{\}]*)}/g){
   push(@biblables, "\\cite{$2}");
}

print join ', ', @biblables;
print ".\n";
```

Comment: Output is ok... there is way in inside while loop?

Comment: Why do you want to do it inside the loop?

Comment: @Borodin: This is just my request if there is a way for simplifying into the while loop. For example if I want to store all the list items in array and I don't want to alter the arrays once stored. May be in future there is a chance in a perl code to write in some situation. That's all.

Answer (score 1):

If you're determine to add the comma's and dots to the elements when
matching in the regex while loop, it can be done like this.

Since you don't know the total matches yet, just keep a reference to
the most recently pushed element.
Then append the `,` or `.` as needed.

Code

```
use strict;
use warnings;

$/ = undef;

my $tmp = <DATA>;
my @biblables = ();
my $ref = undef;

while( $tmp =~ /\\bibitem\[([^\[\]]*)\]{([^\{\}]*)}/g )
{
   $$ref .= ", " if defined $ref;
   $ref = \$biblables[ push(@biblables,"\\cite{$2}") ];
}
$$ref .= "." if defined $ref;

print @biblables;

__DATA__    
\bibitem[{BuI (2001)}]{BuI2001}    
\bibitem[{BuII (2002)}]{BuI2002}    
\bibitem[{BuIII (2003)}]{BuI2003}    
\bibitem[{BuIV (2004)}]{BuI2004}    
\bibitem[{BuV (2005)}]{BuI2005}    
\bibitem[{BuVI (2006)}]{BuI2006}
```

Output

```
\cite{BuI2001}, \cite{BuI2002}, \cite{BuI2003}, \cite{BuI2004}, \cite{BuI2005}, \cite{BuI2006}.
```